# Universal Image Loader on Listview is laggy

Tags: android, listview, lag, universal-image-loader

I have made sure that I only have one instance of ImageLoader so I know that that is not the issue, for some reason, it only lags when it displays a brand new image loaded from the web. So I'm assuming it has something to do with the fact that the UI stutters because it's decoding the image, but I though Universal Image Loader handled everything asynchronously. Here's what I have for my BaseAdapter's getView method.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    JSONObject thePost = null;
    try { 
        thePost = mPosts.getJSONObject(position).getJSONObject("data");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("errreoroer");
    }

    LinearLayout postItem = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.column_post, parent, false);   

    String postThumbnailUrl = null;


    try {

        //parse thumbnail
        postThumbnailUrl = thePost.getString("thumbnail");          

    } catch (Exception e) {}        

    //grab the post view objects

    ImageView postThumbnailView = (ImageView)postItem.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

    if (!(postThumbnailUrl.equals("self") || postThumbnailUrl.equals("default") || postThumbnailUrl.equals("nsfw")))
        mImageLoader.displayImage(postThumbnailUrl, postThumbnailView);         


    return postItem;

}
```

Comment: [This I/O Talk](http://youtu.be/wDBM6wVEO70) contains invaluable insight into the topic of ListView (and much of it applies to other AdapterViews as well) I highly recommend you watch this talk so that you understand the mechanism driving the optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is not the ImageLoader. It is the fact that you aren't utilizing the convertView that the system is passing back to you, so you are not recycling Views at all you are just inflating a new one for each and every row of your List.

Try changing your `getView()` method to make use of the convertView:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LinearLayout postItem = convertView
    if(null == postItem){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        postItem = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.column_post, parent, false);   
    }

    JSONObject thePost = null;
    try { 
        thePost = mPosts.getJSONObject(position).getJSONObject("data");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("errreoroer");
    }
    String postThumbnailUrl = null;
    try {

        //parse thumbnail
        postThumbnailUrl = thePost.getString("thumbnail");          

    } catch (Exception e) {}        

    //grab the post view objects
    ImageView postThumbnailView = (ImageView)postItem.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    if (!(postThumbnailUrl.equals("self") || postThumbnailUrl.equals("default") || postThumbnailUrl.equals("nsfw")))
        mImageLoader.displayImage(postThumbnailUrl, postThumbnailView);         

    return postItem;

}
```

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you so much, saved me quite the headache.